# "Made of" vs "made from"

Tags: prepositions

An English book tells me that the following sentence is correct:

> This publication is made **from paper** from sustainable forests.

Shouldn't it be *of paper* instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no issue of *should/shouldn't* involved here - it's just a stylistic choice.

I think the writer in this case chose to use *from* because *made of* more strongly implies that the publication is *nothing more than paper*, whereas *from* carries more the implication of *using* (perhaps along with other ingredients).

That's to say, the publication in total is made from/using many things (including the labour of the writer, publisher, etc). And possibly some old recycled rags, since pure wood-pulp paper isn't always of the best quality.

A similar situation arises with toilet rolls, which are often claimed to be made *from recycled paper*. The manufacturers know perfectly well that toilet paper made *entirely of recycled paper* isn't actually much good. They don't want to call attention to the fact that there is probably some fresh wood-pulp in the mix; using the word *from* helps present things the way they want.

Answer (score 0):

Both are found, but evidence from British and American corpora and from the Oxford English Dictionary shows that *made of* is much more common than *made from*.

Comment: Not scientific, I know, but googling quotated "made **of** paper from sustainable forests" returns 611 hits, where the same using **from** returns 2120 results. All other things being equal, I'd expect many people to try and avoid repeating the word "from" in this context, so there must be a fairly strong pressure from some other quarter making them still do it.

Comment: Even less scientific, but ‘made of’ produces 7,390,000,000 results, ‘made from, 5,000,000,000!

Comment: Yes, but we are very specifically concerned with why "product description writers" apparently prefer this somewhat ungainly repetition of *from*, when the rest of the world prefers *of* even when there's not necessarily any repetition involved.

Comment: Perhaps for that very reason.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in food labels the difference between "made of" and "made from" becomes important because of legal considerations. Roughly speaking, if the label says "made of natural ingredients" then the food is supposed to consist entirely of natural ingredients; "made from natural ingredients," on the other hand, only implies that some natural ingredients are present.  (The exact legal requirements probably vary from one country to another; in particular, "some natural ingredients" may mean a specified minimum percentage.)

Comment: I think it's highly unlikely that any legislature in any Anglophone country has ever enacted a "legal" distinction between being *made **of*** and *made **from*** whatever ingredient is being promoted by the producer/seller.

Answer (score -2):

As it is clear to me that (made from) is used when the substance that used for producing  another or new object we have to use made from e.g. the table is made from wood. On other hand, we  use (made of) when the substance from which the new object is produced is not clearly visible .g. Money is made of cotton.