# Made from vs made up of for dishes

Tags: meaning, idioms

If I want to question someone about what makes up a given dish, which of the following sentences is the most appropriate ?

> 1. What is this dish made up of ?
> 2. What is this dish made from ?

It seems to me that the first sentence is more appropriate when we want to know all of the food found on a dish while the second one is more for ingredients, am I right ?

In addition to the proper way to question a person, how can we answer someone who asked us to describe a given dish ?

> This dish is composed of eggs, french fries, rice ...

Is this construction fine or is there a more proper way to say that ?

Comment: None of those sounds right.  Things are just made of or made from other things.

Comment: Can you suggest one that sounds right ?

Comment: You could use either “this dish is made **of** this and that” or that is it “made **from** this or that”.  You might even try “made **with** this or that”, but that might suggest you didn’t list all the ingredients.

Comment: possible duplicate of [made of vs made up of](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117036/made-of-vs-made-up-of). Also ['Made of' vs. 'Made from'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65892/made-of-vs-made-from) and [“Made of” vs “made from”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46163/made-of-vs-made-from)

Comment: What are the *ingredients* in this dish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary.com offers two related definitions for *dish*:

> the food served or contained in a dish

and

> a particular article, type, or preparation of food

In my experience (AmE), the second is used more commonly than the first; or at least, when the first is used it implies that only one type of food is placed on the dish.

If you ask "what is this dish made of?" you are asking about a single food item and what ingredients were used to prepare it.

In a restaurant, if several items are served together on one dish, we more often talk about it as a *plate* than a *dish*. In a restaurant it might also be called a *combination*, a *meal*, or a *dinner* (and probably others I'm not thinking of at the moment). In other countries I've seen it called a *set meal* or *set* at restaurants.

If you want to ask what items make up a combination at a restaurant, you can ask, for example,

> What *comes with* the felafel plate?

If you are dining at someone's home, you can ask,

> What are you serving for dinner?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer, for both sentences 1. & 2. : "made with" or rather "prepared with".

Or better : "What is used for / to prepare / to cook this dish ?"

And, for the last one, something more direct : "To prepare this dish, you use / need ...". Or : "..., ..., ..., and ... are used to cook this dish"

Answer (score 1):

You say, "ask", which implies a spoken question, hence, informal.  I would ask "What is this dish made of?"  Or simply, point (or indicate the dish) and ask "What's this made of?"

"Made from" is probably more correct - at least in writing - but in informal speech, "made of" is OK.

(We assume that you're asking about what's ON the dish, not what the dish itself is made of (clay, porocelain, plastic, &c.))